# How to prevent `autocmd` for stripping trailing whitespace for moving the cursor?

Tags: autocmd, insert-mode, normal-mode

I've the following `autocmd` for stripping trailing whitespace in a buffer, every time the buffer is written to a file:

```
" trim whitespace
autocmd BufWritePre * %s/\s\+$//e
```

However, the `autocmd` has the annoying side effect of moving the cursor, when there are lines that match the substitution: `%s/\s\+$//e`

How can I prevent the `autocmd` from moving the cursor?

Comment: Shuzeng, I think you’ve already asked this question and had it closed. Please refrain from repeatedly asking the same question. If you can clarify what in the multitude of linked questions doesn’t help you, please [edit] and we can reopen.